# PHP Clone Extended Object, DateTime Reference is the Same

Tags: php, clone

Right this turns out to be a pretty tough one to explain, I'm creating calendar events that have shared details but on different dates.

So I'm doing something like the following, note the **clone**:

```
    // Create event for each subject
    $event = new CalendarEvent();
    $event->setTitle($subject->getTitle());

    // Add an event for every occurrence
    // -- getDates() returns an array of DateTime objects
    foreach($subject->getDates() as $date) {
        $dateEvent = clone $event;

        $dateEvent->setStartDate($date);

        $events[] = $dateEvent;
    }
```

However if I dump the `$events` array, we can see that each event start date is pointing to the same reference:

```
Add:object(CalendarEvent)#2406 (5) {
  ["startDateTime":"Event":private]=>
  object(DateTime)#2411 (3) {
    ["date"]=>
    string(19) "2013-10-02 09:00:00"
    ["timezone_type"]=>
    int(3)
    ["timezone"]=>
    string(13) "Europe/Berlin"
  }
  ... trimmed ...
}
Add:object(CalendarEvent)#2413 (5) {
  ["startDateTime":"Event":private]=>
  object(DateTime)#2411 (3) {
    ["date"]=>
    string(19) "2013-10-16 09:00:00"
    ["timezone_type"]=>
    int(3)
    ["timezone"]=>
    string(13) "Europe/Berlin"
  }
  ... trimmed ...
}
Add:object(CalendarEvent)#2414 (5) {
  ["startDateTime":"Event":private]=>
  object(DateTime)#2411 (3) {
    ["date"]=>
    string(19) "2013-11-06 09:00:00"
    ["timezone_type"]=>
    int(3)
    ["timezone"]=>
    string(13) "Europe/Berlin"
  }
  ... trimmed ...
}
```

Every events startDateTime is pointing to **#2411** this means that all the events appear to have the same time even though the provided start dates are different.

Why is this happening? I thought copy would create a new copy of the DateTime in memory to point to.

`Event->SetStartDate` is the just the following and in the constructor I create a new DateTime for each event:

```
  public function setStartDate(DateTime $date) {
    $this->startDateTime->setDate($date->format('Y'), $date->format('m'), $date->format('d'));
  }
```

Moving `new CalendarEvent()` inside the loop fixes the problem but I'm wondering why this happens at all? Why are all the cloned events pointing to the same `DateTime` instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PHP `clone` is **NOT** recursive, so you should replace

```
$dateEvent->setStartDate($date);
```

with

```
$dateEvent->setStartDate(clone $date);
```

See also the docs: http://php.net/language.oop5.cloning

> When an object is cloned, PHP 5 will perform a shallow copy of all of
>   the object's properties. Any properties that are references to other
>   variables, will remain references.

Here is a pretty rough deep clone implementation:

```
/**
 * Implement PHP __clone to create a deep clone, not just a shallow copy.
 */
public function __clone() {
    foreach($this as $key => $val) {
        if (is_object($val) || (is_array($val))) {
            $this->{$key} = unserialize(serialize($val));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I see, looks like I misunderstood how clone works. Is it possible to do a deep copy?

Comment: I assume that would do something like `$this->start = clone $this->start`?